# Enviar datos sin formulario a php con ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Hola tengo un problema al enviar un dato al pulsar un boton a php que viene como parámetro en JavaScript al parecer no me envía nada y solo me regresa la respuesta de que si se ha enviado

este es el boton:

```
<li><a class="eliminarProducto" type="submit" data-productoid="9582" href="javascript:deleteP(<?php 
echo($name); ?>);">Eliminar producto</a></li>
        </ul>
</li>
```

y este es la funcion que realiza el boton:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function deleteP(id){
        $.ajax({
            url: "eliminar.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: id,
            success : function (result){
                alert(result);
            }
            
        }).done(function(info){
            alert(info);
        });
    }
</script>
```

quiero enviar el parametro id al php eliminar pero el php no recibe nada:
esto es lo que tengo en el php

```
print_r($_POST);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En `data`, tienes que enviar un objeto, donde asocias cada valor con una clave. Prueba así: `data: {id: id},`, ahí el valor `id` irá asociado a una clave (la clave es el valor de la izquierda, que en este caso se llama `id`). Ahí, en `$_POST[' id']` tendrás el valor que se envío asociado a esa clave.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que tu parámetro `data` es incorrecto:

```
        data: id,
```

Traduzco aquí [lo que explica jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) con respecto al parámetro `data` en las peticiones Ajax:

> ### `data`
>
> Tipo: [PlainObject](https://api.jquery.com/Types/#PlainObject) o [String](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#String) o [Array](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Array)
>
> Datos a enviar al servidor. Si el método HTTP es uno que no puede
> tener un cuerpo de entidad, como `GET`, los datos se añaden a la URL.
>
> Cuando los datos son un objeto, jQuery genera la cadena de datos a
> partir de los pares clave/valor del objeto, a menos que la opción
> `processData` esté establecida en false. Por ejemplo, `{a: "bc", d: "e, f"}` se convierte en la cadena `"a=bc&d=e%2Cf"`. Si el valor es
> una matriz, jQuery serializa varios valores con la misma clave en
> función del valor de la configuración tradicional (que se describe a
> continuación). Por ejemplo, `{a: [1,2]}` se convierte en la cadena
> `"a%5B%5D=1&a%5B%5D=2"` con la configuración predeterminada
> `traditional: false`.
>
> Cuando `data` se pasa como una cadena, **ya debería esta codificada**
> con la codificación correcta para `contentType`, que de forma
> predeterminada es `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.
>
> En solicitudes con `dataType: "json"` o `dataType: "jsonp"`, si la
> cadena contiene un doble signo de interrogación (`??`) en cualquier
> lugar de la URL o un solo signo de interrogación (`?`) en la cadena de
> consulta, se reemplaza con un valor generado por jQuery que es único
> para cada copia de la biblioteca en la página (por ejemplo,
> `jQuery21406515378922229067_1479880736745`).

Significa que para este caso, podrías pasar una cadena o, mejor aún, un objeto plano (plain object).

Por ejemplo:

```
        data: {id: id},
```

Aquí, se enviará al servidor el dato (valor que tenga `id` a la derecha) asociado a una clave llamada `id` (valor puesto a la izquierda sin más). Si pusieras algo así: `data: {xlshjfg: id},` la clave sería `xlshjfg`, pero no tiene mucho sentido ponerle esa clave, mejor le ponemos `id` (digo esto para que quede claro que lo que está a la izquierda sería la clave).

En el caso de necesitar enviar varios valores, el objeto plano sería así por ejemplo:

```
        data: { id: id, 
                nombre: "valor Nombre", 
                apellido: "valor Apellido", 
                etc: "valor etc"
              },
```

Se pone cada par clave/valor separado por coma. Así podrás encontrar los valores haciendo algo como: `$_POST['id']`, `$_POST['nombre']`, `$_POST['etc']`.

Otra forma de enviarlo sería al estilo url encoded:

```
"id="+id+"&nombre=valor%20Nombre&apellido=valor%20Apellido&etc=valor%20etc"
```

Es una forma algo más *fea*, sobre todo cuando hay que enviar varios datos.